# How to seal gas hob to concrete countertop?

Tags: appliances, gas, sealing, kitchen-counters

Some time this week, I'll be calling a qualified technician to connect my gas hob to gas and electricity. Connection will be done with elastic pipe, so that's not a problem.

The only problem I have is that there is a hole in the countertop, obviously. And I do not want any spillage to get underneath the hob. Especially not between the cover part (blue on schematics) and supporting structure (read on schematics). On the other hand, I cannot install rubber U shaped seal on the edge of the top cover part, because it would introduce tension, and that is strictly forbidden for this hob due to gas-related safety reasons. Also, anything used must be able to routinely endure 90°C (roughly 200°F).

And last but not least, I do not want to put a silicone there, as it would ruin the steel on concrete look I aim for.

So, is there any way to do it reliably and safely without ruining the look?

---

To be clear, I'm not prejudiced against the silicone. Simply, I just don't know how to do it in a way that'll seal the "blue" part without being too visible.

[image: Cross Section Diagram]
[image: Hob photo]

Comment: If done neatly & correctly, silicone would be invisible as it would all be contained between the hob(blue) and counter-top/support(red). So as a result I don't really understand your objection to silicone. Temperature is a non-issue as long as you choose the correct silicone.

Comment: @brhans I need advice on how to get it done neatly and correctly, then. It would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: I have a similar style of gas cooktop on a laminate countertop. Installer (my HVAC guy - I wouldn't do it myself because of the gas hookup) cut the hole (the previous cooktop was slightly smaller so it needed to be expanded on one side) and installed and used (I am 99+% certain) clear silicone - it is only noticeable if I look for it - really not a problem at all.

Comment: @manassehkatz hole I have, I poured it with a hole to specs. Gas hookup will be done by professional. In my country people with gas installation permit usually do not do things other than just gas connection, and I cannot afford to hire a whole team for this job.

Comment: In my country, a **lot** depends on the person. Typically a big company will very strictly limit what the employees do/don't do, or charge a lot extra (even if it turns out to be the same person doing all the work) for extras. The small companies (like my one-man HVAC guy who worked for a bigger company years ago) will do whatever you ask, and the trick is finding someone you can trust to tell you if things are beyond their capabilities. My guy is a perfectionist (I knew this from when I was redoing a bathroom and he pushed *me* to do a better job on my part before he would come in and do the

Comment: plumbing work. So when he told me cutting the hole larger wouldn't be "perfect" with his tools, I knew enough to know his "imperfect" would be far more than adequate - and in fact the only part not "perfect" is hidden under the cooktop.